# AFNetworking The network connection was lost error

Tags: ios, uiimageview, afnetworking-2

I have a `UICollectionView` where every cell has some data like name, price and image. I'm using `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:` method from `<UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>` to download image from url like `http://serveraddress/images/19/918324402131722.jpg`. Everything works fine when I'm scrolling fast. The problem appears when I'm scrolling really fast. Then some (let say 5% of requests) failed with error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."
UserInfo=0x7fafbf64e6c0 {
     NSUnderlyingError=0x7fafbf3d65c0 "The network connection was lost.",
     NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://serveraddress/images/19/918324402131722.jpg, 
     NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://serveraddress/images/19/918324402131722.jpg, 
     _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, 
     _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54,
     NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.
}
```

Also notice, when cell will be reload by moving on screen again, everything works fine and image appears. Here's my code:

```
- (ProductCollectionCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ProductCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ProductCollectionCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Product *product = _model.products[indexPath.row];
[cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
@weakify(cell);
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[product thumbURLRequest] placeholderImage:nil
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                   @strongify(cell);
                                   [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                   [cell.imageView setImage:image];

                               } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                   @strongify(cell);
                                   [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                   [cell setFailedPlaceholder];
                               }];
return cell;
}
```

**NOTE:** I red and tried all possible and reasonable solutions which I found on SOF.
I'm using AFNetworking version 2.4.1.

Any idea how to fix it? It's possible that is server fault?